# Sharing memory buffer in a producer consumer semaphore

Tags: c, memory, mutex, semaphore, producer-consumer

I have a question on how to implement using a shared memory buffer in semaphore sets. I am doing the classic consumer producer problem where I add a new item to a buffer stack and depending on the scheduler I want to remove the first in item produced from my producer.
Below is my producer and consumer code :

```
int produce_item(){
    int item = rand()%50 +1;
    printf("Producer produces %d\n",item);
    sleep(1);
    return item;
}

void consume_item(int item){
    printf("Consumer consumes %d\n",item);
    sleep(2);
}
void* consumer(void * arg) {
    int item, j=0;
    while(1){
        down(full);
        down(mutex);    
        consume_item(item);
        buffer[j++] = item; 
        up(mutex);
        up(empty);
    }
    return 0;
}

void* producer(void* arg) { 
    int item, i;
    while(1){
        item  = produce_item();
        down(empty);
        down(mutex);
        buffer[i++]=item;
        up(mutex);
        up(full);
        sleep(1);
    }
```

my buffer is decalred as a global variable

and here is a test run which shows my question, why is it only consuming the same item over and over again?

```
Consumer consumes 32622
Producer produces 16
Consumer consumes 32622
Producer produces 22
Consumer consumes 32622
Producer produces 1
Consumer consumes 32622
Producer produces 16
Consumer consumes 32622
Producer produces 15
```

Comment: `item` is uninitialised.

Comment: the function produce_item returns a rand number up to 50

Comment: what about the `consume_item` ?

Comment: `i` is uninitialised.

Comment: consume_item does nothing but print out the item, I am unsure how to remove from buffer.

Comment: But `item` is uninitalised when passed to `consume_item`. Too much missing code to be sure what is happening. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: why do we need to initialize item when it is being creating before we consume it. Do i need to pass it in as an argument to the consumer function?

Comment: Don't know what you mean. But generally if you are passing a variable to a function then that variable needs to have a valid value for the function to use right? `printf("Consumer consumes %d\n",item);` what do you expect that to print since `item` has not been set to any value? It is Undefined Behaviour.